# Add all functions from a module as methods of an object without code duplication?

Tags: python

How would you add all functions from some module as methods of a specified object?

If you have module `modulename` you can import all it's methods with

```
from modulename import *
```

I want to add them as methods of some `obj` instead cause they all accept that object as the first paramater and I find `x.y(z)` to be more fun than `y(x,z)` because of habit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import modulename

class Obj(object):
    ...

obj_ = Obj()

for name, func in getmembers(modulename, isfunction):
    setattr(obj_, name, func)

print(obj_.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_methods(driver):
  for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
    if inspect.isfunction(obj) and name != 'add_methods':
      setattr(driver, name, obj.__get__(driver))
```